# Difference between ADDNES and ADDSNE

Tags: assembly, arm

I am having trouble with understanding the difference between `ADDNES` and `ADDSNE` in ARM assembly. Please can someone help me, with some examples?

Comment: See last item in Table 14 [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/Cjagjjbc.html) (UAL stands for [Unified Assembly Language](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/BABJIHGJ.html)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're different spellings for the same instruction.  Clang, for example, can only handle the  `addnes` format, but `otool` outputs `addsne` when disassembling it.

Example:

```
$ cat example.s
  addnes r0, r0, #1
$ clang -arch arm -c -o example.o example.s
$ otool -tV example.o 
example.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
00000000    12900001    addsne  r0, r0, #1  @ 0x1
```

But if trying to use the `addnse` spelling in clang:

```
$ cat example.s
  addsne r0, r0, #1
$ clang -arch arm -c -o example.o example.s
example.s:1:bad instruction `addsne r0,r0,#1'
clang: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is one of those confusing things about arm assembly, all instructions have the condition field, some instructions have extra stuff like add and adds, where does the ne or eq or mi, etc go.  Before the s or after?  add+ne+s addnes or add+s+ne.  I would hope the tools take both, but it sounds from the accepted answer that it is worse than that, some take one some take the other.